# search(query) throws NullPointerException

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

```
    public List<DHProductLookupModel> findProductbyCCsapProductId(final String code)
{
    final String queryString = "SELECT {p:" + DHProductLookupModel.SAPPRODUCTID + "}" + "FROM{" + DHProductLookupModel._TYPECODE
            + " AS p}" + "WHERE" + "{p:" + DHProductLookupModel.SAPPRODUCTID + "}=?code ";
    final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery(queryString);
    query.addQueryParameter("code", code);
    return flexibleSearchService.<DHProductLookupModel> search(query).getResult();
}
```

search(query) throws Null Pointer Exception, how to handle this?

Output:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.getJaloResult(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:396) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.search.impl.DefaultFlexibleSearchService.search(DefaultFlexibleSearchService.java:168) ~[coreserver.jar:?]
    at com.cancom.core.productlookup.dao.impl.CCProductLookupDaoImpl.findProductbyCCmanufacturerProductId(CCProductLookupDaoImpl.java:39) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.cancom.core.productlookup.service.impl.CCProductLookupServiceImpl.getProductforCCmanufacturerProductId(CCProductLookupServiceImpl.java:37) ~[classes/:?]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Change your flexible search query from

```
 final String queryString = "SELECT {p:" + DHProductLookupModel.SAPPRODUCTID + "}" + "FROM{" + DHProductLookupModel._TYPECODE
        + " AS p}" + "WHERE" + "{p:" + DHProductLookupModel.SAPPRODUCTID + "}=?code ";
```

to

```
 final String queryString = "SELECT {p:" + DHProductLookupModel.PK + "}" + "FROM{" + DHProductLookupModel._TYPECODE
        + " AS p}" + "WHERE" + "{p:" + DHProductLookupModel.SAPPRODUCTID + "}=?code ";
```

You should send `DHProductLookupModel.PK` in search result.

Comment: I tried with     DHProductLookupModel.PK but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use **getModelsByExample** of **flexibleSearchService** instead of writing the query.

Your method will be like

```
 public List<DHProductLookupModel> findProductbyCCsapProductId(final String code)
 {
     DHProductLookupModel dhProductLookupModel = new DHProductLookupModel();
     dhProductLookupModel.setSapProductID(code);
     return getFlexibleSearchService().getModelsByExample(dhProductLookupModel);
 }
```

---

### [find the example here](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/models-by-example-in-hybris-flexible-Search.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!
I found the Problem. It was in my spring.I just had to put :

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="myPackage"/>
```

I changed also the query with DHProductLookupModel.PK for safety. Now it´s work!